# SQL Statement - Mass Delete Custom Post Types

Tags: mysql

This website lists a nice way of deleting posts based on category

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/06/how-to-effectively-bulk-delete-many-posts-in-wordpress.html

The relevant code is:

```
delete a,b,c,d
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE e.term_id =<category id>
```

where `<category id>` needs to be replaced with the relevant number.

I need to modify this code to mass delete custom post types based on their taxonomy.

By pressing on the edit button in wordpress admin i can retrieve the following information:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=estate_agents&tag_ID=9098&post_type=os_estate
```

So i will need to modify the SQL code above to take:

```
post_type= os_estate
taxonomy= estate_agents
tag_ID= 9098
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust you have backed up your wordpress database. In any case, as the article suggests, worth trying with a select statement first to see which posts are returned:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_type, post_status, d.taxonomy, e.name
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE d.taxonomy = 'estate_agents' AND a.post_type = 'os_estate' AND e.term_id = 9098
```

Then, if you're happy:

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE d.taxonomy = 'estate_agents' AND a.post_type = 'os_estate' AND e.term_id = 9098
```

Specifying `DELETE a,b,c` means that only rows in the wp_posts, wp_term_relationships and wp_postmeta tables will be deleted; rows in wp_term_taxonomy (d) and wp_terms (e) will not.

Comment: thank you Jon, will try this out shortly! What if i want to include multiple term_ID= 9098, 9099 and so on... how would i modify your code? "All term_id" are included within taxonomy "estate_agents"

Comment: As for the comment: Make use of the [MySQL `IN` comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). `WHERE d.taxonomy = 'estate_agents' AND a.post_type = 'os_estate' AND e.term_id IN ( 9098, 9099, 9100 )`

Comment: @Jon ok there is a problem with the code - it also deletes the taxonomy name - there are other posts inside that taxonomy and hence I wouldn't like the taxonomy name to be deleted...

Comment: @Mario yes you're right. Removing `,d` (the *alias* for the taxonomy table) from the delete statement will fix this. I have updated the answer